# How to change taskbar color and sf symbol colors?

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image: SF SYMBOLS]

how can i change the tab bars background color **and** the sf symbols to a custom color?i've tried background(Color: color) under the .tabitem, above it, inside the brackets
i tried for the symbols to do .palette (bc i made a custom color i want to use) but idk if bc it's in a label i cant modify it? I also tried .foregroundcolor as well. What's missing?

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
        
            
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Text("Logout")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Logout", systemImage: "arrow.left")
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    
                    Text("Home")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }

            }
            
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
        
                Text("Home")
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Text("Add")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
            }

            
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    
                    Text("Ship")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Ship", systemImage: "shippingbox")
            }
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Text("Order")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
            }
            .tabItem{
                Label("Order", systemImage: "bag")
            }
            NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                    Text("Reports")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
            }
            .tabItem  {
                Label("Reports", systemImage: "doc")
                
            }
            
            
        }
      
        
        
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with accent colour for selected tab items and appearance modifications for other things

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

[image: demo]

```
struct Home: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .white
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
        }
        .accentColor(.yellow)
    }
}
```